# How can I render the string `{{string}}` within a jsrender template?

Tags: escaping, jsrender

Is it possible to render a string wrapped in double curly braces in JSRender?

```
<div>
   <p>Can I render {{string}} instead of something looking like a {{customtag}}?</p>
   {{if myCustomTag && myTag}}
      (<em>{{:myTag}}</em>)
   {{/if}}
</div>
```

So far my attempts at http://www.jsviews.com/ have come back void.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML character entities - `&#123;` for `{` and `&#125;` for `}` (or equivalently `&lcub;` and `&rcub;`)

So in a template,

`... &#123;&#123;string&#125;&#125; ...`

will render as

`... {{string}} ...`

In fact the parser is looking for `{{` and `{^{` as tag delimiters, so you can get away with using:

`... {&#123;string&#125;} ...`

---

This is covered by the following new documentation topic:  https://www.jsviews.com/#escapetag

Comment: @Ryan - did that correspond to what you were looking for, and work for you? If not, can you clarify - or create a jsfiddle showing what you are trying to do?

Comment: This is great. Just away for a bit. Upvoted and answer accepted. Sorry for the delay.